# Browser not recognising UTF8

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have UTF8 data in a MYSQL table. I Base64 encode this as it's read from the table and transport it to a web page via PHP and AJAX. Javascript Base64 decodes it as it is inserted into the HTML. The page receiving it is declared to be UTF8.

My problem is that if I insert the Base64 decoded data (using atob()) into the page, any two bytes that make up a single UTF-8 character are presented as two separate Unicode code points. I have to use   "decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(data)))" (learned from another question on this forum, thank you) to get the characters to be represented correctly, and what this process does is convert the two UTF-8 byte to a single byte equaling the unicode code point for the char (also the same char under ISO 8859).

In short, to get the UTF-8 data correctly rendered in a UTF-8 page they have to be converted to their unicode code-point/ISO 8859 values.

An example:

THe unicode code-point for lowercase e-acute is \u00e9. The UTF-8 encoding of this character is \xc3\xa9:

[image]

THe following images show what is rendered for various decodings of my Base64 encoding of this word - first plain atob(), then adding escape() to the process, then further adding decodeURIComponent(). I show the console reporting the output of each, as well as three INPUT fields populated with the three outputs ("record[6]" contains the Base64 encoded data). First the code:

```
console.log(window.atob(record[6]));
console.log(escape(window.atob(record[6])));
console.log(decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(record[6]))));

jQuery("#b64-1").val(window.atob(record[6]));
jQuery("#b64-2").val(escape(window.atob(record[6])));
jQuery("#b64-3").val(decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(record[6]))));
```

`

[image]  [image]

Copy and pasting the two versions of née into a hex editor reveals what has happened

'[image: nee]'

Clearly, the two bytes from the atob() decoding are the correct values for UTF-8 e-acute (\xc3\xa9), but are initially rendered not as a single UTF-8 char, but as two individual chars: C3 (uppercase A tilde) and A9 (copyright sign). The next two steps convert those two chars to the single codepoint for e-acute \u00e9.

So decodeURIComponent() obviously recognises the two bytes as a single UTF-8 character (because it changes them to A9), but not the browser.

Can anyone explain to me why this needs to happen in a page declared to be UTF-8?

(I am using Chrome on W10-64)

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding? Almost everything will support UTF-8, just send the data as-is?

Comment: That does not work for me - I am moving data in JSON and storing the data inside the page as HTML data attributes until it's needed and I had a lot of escaping conflicts so just resorted to B64 end to end - that removed all my grief. Anyway, the fact that the data starts in Base64 is not the point of the question, and the triple encoding/decoding is working. It's the rendering of the data once decoded that has me perplexed and is the issue here.

Comment: Yea, you can't just keep throwing more encoding schemes at a problem until it works. I would highly suggest you remove all these encodings and only use the ones that are appropriate for the context. Are you putting stull in a url? You need to urlencode. Are you encoding within JSON, use json encoding. Do you need to encode binary data in a 6 bit stream? Use base64... What you're doing is kind of ridiculous and clearly it's causing you some problems.

Comment: JSON supports UTF-8, HTML supports UTF-8. To place data in an HTML attribute you don't need anything special if you use the DOM correctly.

Comment: your "clearly" is wrong, I would say obviously wrong. I think you should try to put a complete example (e.g. giving a rec="\x....." string and the test with such strings, and tell us what do you expect, and what do you get). [and without hex editor, you can just do a short JS loop. Not only this will help us, but probably you, finding how things works, and that you (as I'm thinking now) you are wrongly assuming the encoding of the initial data).

Comment: @Evert I disagree. I started with the approach you propose, and ended up with encoding hell. The data move through MySQL strings, JSON format, phpStrings, AJAX, Javascript and finally they're stored in HTML. The bland Base64 character set moves through all of this without needing any encoding or escaping. Base64  encoded data move end to end without an issue. But you and the other (judgemental) commenters are missing the point of the question, which is about the browser rendering of UTF8 characters. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Evert  meaning?

Comment: don't worry - I have looked it up. I'll think about it and try a demo implementation of the problem to see if you're right.

Comment: @evert, if you are interested I have explored this question without the Base64 encoding and have asked a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62796670/utf-8-contradictory-definitions. The base64 was a distraction from the real question about browsers and utf-8.