# UTF-8 - contradictory definitions

Tags: html, unicode, encoding, utf-8

My understanding of UTF-8 encoding is that the first byte of a UTF-8 char carries either

1. data in the lower 7 bits (0-6) with high bit (7) clear for single byte ASCII range code-points
2. data in the lower 5 bits (0-4), with high bits 7-5 = 110 to indicate a 2 byte char
3. data in the lower 4 bits (0-3), with high bits 7-4 = 1110 to indicate a 3 byte char
4. data in the lower 5 bits (0-2), with high bits 7-3 = 11110 to indicate a 4 byte char

noting that bit 7 is always set and this tells utf-8 parsers that this is a multi-byte char.

This means that any unicode code-point in the range 128-255 has to be encoded in 2 or more bytes, because the high bit that is required if they were to be encoded in one byte is reserved in UTF-8 for the 'multi-byte indicator bit'. So e.g. the character é (e-acute, which is unicode code-point \u00E9, 233 decimal) is encoded in UTF-8 as a two byte character \xC3A9.

The following table from [here](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/) shows how the code-point \u00E9 is encoded in UTF-8 as \xC3A9.

[image]
[image]

However this is not how it works in a web page it seems. I have recently had some contradictory behavior in the rendering of unicode chars, and in my exploratory reading came across this:

- "UTF-8 is identical to both ANSI and 8859-1 for the values from 160 to 255." ([w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp))

which clearly contradicts the above.

And if I render these various values in [jsfiddle](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGJVEM2TIMXW) I get

[image: E9 is rendered as é, not \xC3A9]

So HTML is rendering the unicode **code-point** as é, not the UTF-8 2-byte encoding of that code-point. In fact HTML renders the UTF-8 char \xC3A9 as the Hangul syllable that has the code-point \xC3A9:

[image]

[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp) has a table that explicitly defines the UTF-8 of é as Decimal 233 (\xE9):

[image]
[image]

So HTML is rendering code-points, not UTF-8 chars.

Am I missing something here? Can anyone explain to me why in a supposedly  UTF-8  HTML document, it seems like there is no UTF-8 parsing going on at all?

Comment: Quality of w3school is not high. I would not recommend it, and in any case I would never trust 100% this site. The sentence "UTF-8 is identical to both ANSI and 8859-1 for the values from 160 to 255." is obviously wrong. They confuse Unicode with UTF-8. BTW do not write `\xC3A9`: it is confusing and often not what you think (on little endian architectures, like x86).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi w3school might be wrong, but the jsfiddle example shows that the browser is rendering the bytes based on code-points, not the utf-8 charset.

Comment: UTF-8 is just the standard encoding of web, to transfer files. Internally they are just unicode characters, so yes, the codes are not UTF-8 bytes, but codepoints.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-charref : so they are code point

Comment: What is the question here? Is it "Can anyone explain to me why in a supposedly UTF-8 HTML document, it seems like there is no UTF-8 parsing going on at all?" What behavior do you find surprising, what were you expecting?

Comment: @Joni I was expecting UTF-8 characters passed to the browser to be rendered correctly. But Remy Lebeau has enlightened me in his answer so all is well.

Comment: ANSI is not a defined encoding, but in this case is referring to what looks like Windows-1252 (The Western European and USA default code page in Windows).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_character_set.  The UTF-8 table is not right at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of the encoding of UTF-8 bytes is correct.

Your jsfiddle example is using UTF-8 only as a byte encoding for the HTML file (hence the use of the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` HTML tag), but not as an encoding of the HTML itself.  HTML only uses ASCII characters for its markup, but that markup can *represent* Unicode characters.

UTF-8 is a byte encoding for Unicode codepoints.  It is commonly used for transmissions of Unicode data, such as an HTML file over HTTP.  But HTML itself is defined in terms of Unicode codepoints only, not in UTF-8 specifically.  A webbrowser would receive the raw UTF-8 bytes over the wire and decode them to Unicode codepoints before processing them in the context of the HTML.

HTML entities deal in Unicode codepoints only, not in codeunits, such as used in UTF-8.

HTML entities in `&#<xxx>;` format represent Unicode codepoints by their numeric values directly.

- `&#233;` (é) and `&#xE9;` (é) represent integer 233 in decimal and hex formats, respectively. 233 is the numeric value of Unicode codepoint [`U+00E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm), which is encoded in UTF-8 bytes as `0xC3 0xA9`.
- `&#xc3a9;` (쎩) represents integer 50089 in hex format (0xC3A9). 50089 is the numeric value of Unicode codepoint [`U+C3A9 HANGUL SYLLABLE SSYEOLG`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c3a9/index.htm), which is encoded in UTF-8 as bytes `0xEC 0x8E 0xA9`.

HTML entities in `&<name>;` format represent Unicode codepoints by a human-readable name defined by HTML.

- `&eacute;` (é) represents Unicode codepoint `U+00E9`, same as `&#233;` and `&#xE9;` do.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau, for me the key sentence in your answer is "A webbrowser would receive the raw UTF-8 bytes over the wire and decode them to Unicode codepoints". So the rendering process does not recognise UTF-8, just code-points? Does this mean that if javascript receives data or markup in UTF-8 from, say, an AJAX exchange, it has to perform this decoding into code-points before injecting the content into the DOM? - because that is my experience, and the reason I asked the question.

Comment: @Nikkorian "*So the rendering process does not recognise UTF-8, just code-points?*" - yes. "*Does this mean that if javascript receives data or markup in UTF-8 from, say, an AJAX exchange, it has to perform this decoding into code-points before injecting the content into the DOM?*"- yes. The DOM has no concept of UTF encodings, only Unicode itself. However, in memory, Javascript and DOM strings are typically encoded in UTF-16 as an implementation detail.

Comment: And in reverse? If I am delivering data captured in an INPUT via AJAX, will the data be in code-points, and do I have to convert to UTF-8 before sending?

Comment: @Nikkorian YOU shouldn't have to, the AJAX api should handle that for you. But yes, DOM/script strings will have to be encoded on the wire, and UTF-8 is the preferred encoding for that..

Comment: Thank you Remy - it is all starting to make sense.

Comment: I have been using window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str))), and its reverse, to achieve this, without understanding why I had to. Is there a better way?

Comment: @Nikkorian that should be posted separately as its own question.